# search in restricted access folders

Tags: c#, restriction

I want to list all files and folders that my program has access to and write them to a text file. i write a method which help me do this but in some cases (folder is access denied) my program stop working.
i search here a lot and find some links that said use try/catch and sth else but i cant fix my problem yet.

```
string spcdirectorypath = @"C:\Users";
            string spcfiletape = "*.*";
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(spcdirectorypath);//Assuming Test is your Folder
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles(spcfiletape, SearchOption.AllDirectories); //Getting Text files
            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
                {
                    string str = file.FullName + "\n";
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(str);
                }
```

now how can i fix this problem? or in other hands can i access to that restricted folders? sorry for this repetitive Q and thanks for best answers :)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check th permissions before trying to list the files, if you want to avoid unauthorized access exceptions.

Here I adapt for your case [the example of MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) about walking a directory tree :

```
void YourMethod()
{
   string spcdirectorypath = @"C:\Users";
   DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(spcdirectorypath);

   WalkDirectoryTree(d)
}

static void WalkDirectoryTree(System.IO.DirectoryInfo root)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

    // First, process all the files directly under this folder 
    try
    {
        files = root.GetFiles("*.*");
    }
    // This is thrown if even one of the files requires permissions greater 
    // than the application provides. 
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you 
        // can try to elevate your privileges and access the file again.
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        // You may decide to do something different here. For example, you 
        // can log soething.
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            // In this example, we only access the existing FileInfo object. If we 
            // want to open, delete or modify the file, then 
            // a try-catch block is required here to handle the case 
            // where the file has been deleted since the call to TraverseTree().
            string str = fi.FullName + "\n";
            richTextBox1.AppendText(str);
        }

        // Now find all the subdirectories under this directory.
        subDirs = root.GetDirectories();

        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
        {
            // Resursive call for each subdirectory.
            WalkDirectoryTree(dirInfo);
        }
    }            
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i test it but this error appear: An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\UpdatusUser\Templates' is denied.

Comment: See my edit, the second issue of your original code is that you were getting the entire structure in a single call through `SearchOption.AllDirectories`

Comment: your new issue help me and i fix the problem and i am very grateful about this. just an error in your code: " **static void WalkDirectoryTree** " should change to " **private void WalkDirectoryTree** " in order to accept `richTextBox1.AppendText(str)`. also this code is too heavy for compute and system go to not responding mode but i will use Thread method for fixing this. anyway now my program is work and i say Thank you to you ;)

Answer (score 0):

The process under which you are running your program should have the required privileges otherwise you wont be able access the folder and enumerate the files. In your test environment make sure you run this code as an administrator.

Comment: i test this way (run as administrator) now but problem not fixed.

Comment: There's some folders you simply can't access, not without a shadow copy (which is a bit of an overkill). For example, `System Volume Information`. It's not about permissions, it's more like concurrency in a way.

Comment: Then in that case open a command prompt [As an Administrator] and try accessing the folder and listing the contents of the folder. If you can't access the folders or list the files then you don't have the sufficient privilege. This makes sense otherwise everybody would access each others files.

Comment: Let us know more details about your program. Windows desktop application? Web application?

Comment: @alex.pulver Windows desktop app in c# and program force error in adresses like C:\Users\UpdatusUser\Templates

Comment: @Socrates i just do this but i forced to error again.

Comment: If you did that command prompt test and you still have access issue then you don't have the privilege.Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Just skip those directories. If it fails, ignore:

```
try
{
  foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(spcdirectorypath))
  {
    richTextBox1.AppendText(file + "\r\n");
  }
}
catch (IOException)
{
  richTextBox1.AppendText("Failed " + spcdirectoryPath + "\r\n");
}
```

If the exception is not an IOException, just change it to the one that actually gets thrown.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that UpdatusUser is a user on that machine. User folders have restricted permissions. Try to run your application under UpdatusUser. If you don't run your application with UpdatusUser, you may try to set permission on UpdatusUser folder for your user (right-click on folder Properties/Security).

If you still encounter issues go deeper and see what is blocking using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx).