# Asynchronous task using Task.Factory.StartNew()

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, console, scheduled-tasks

At some point of execution of our project we are using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` for creating asynchronous tasks. which are required to delete some temporary files. following is the code i am using for this :

```
 Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() deleteTempDocs(path))
```

The problem is that some folders may have privilege restrictions. so i need to run this tasks with `Administrator Rights`. even if my project is not running in admin Rights. is it possible to set rights like this?

Comment: You definitely want to gain access to those restricted folders, or is it good enough to catch the exception, as done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950102/search-in-restricted-access-folders)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to run a task with Administrator rights, as rights are assigned on a process level. You would have to start a new process, for example a batch file, and get it to run as administrator.

```
var process = new Process();
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

processStartInfo.Verb = "runas"; // runs as Administrator
processStartInfo.FileName = "myFileDeleter.exe";
process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
process.Start();   
process.WaitForExit();
```